# How to rename a git folder that has a submodule in its sub-directory

Tags: git, git-submodules

My folder structure is:

> ~/git_project/bad_name/some/folder/structure/submodule_folder/

I would like to change it to:

> ~/git_project/better_name/some/folder/structure/submodule_folder/

So I did:

```
cd git_project
git mv bad_name better_name
```

When I checked my git status after this command, I got this:

```
fatal: Could not chdir to '../../../../../../../bad_name/some/folder/structure/submodule_folder': No such file or directory
fatal: 'git status --porcelain' failed in submodule better_name/some/folder/structure/submodule_folder
```

How do you rename a folder that has submodule in its sub-directories?

Comment: look at this [example](https://riptutorial.com/git/example/12495/moving-a-submodule)

Comment: This example has a slightly different scenario. I tried to follow it but I get the error 'fatal: bad source' when I run: git mv bad_name better_name, because the 'better_name' folder is no longer empty. I need todo a git mv in order to keep the commit history.

Answer (score -1):

Git can only understand files, it cannot track an empty directory.

Create a dummy file (.gitkeep) in your empty directory using:

```
cd git_project

touch bad_name/some/folder/structure/submodule_folder/.gitkeep
```

And then do:

```
git mv bad_name better_name
```

Comment: My question is not about empty directories. It is about git submodules. Your answear does not address that.